# Refresh all components of Pentaho CDE dashboard

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to be able to **refresh** entire `Pentaho CDE dashboard` including **all components** using a button.

Currently I use this code `window.location.reload()`, which refreshes whole HTML page. But it reloads all resources, which makes it slow.

Is there a way of how to refresh all components of Pentaho CDE dashboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use and call this function:

```
function updateAllDashboardComponents() {
    Dashboards.updateAll(Dashboards.components);
}
```

Comment: is it possible that i refresh a report, like on button click, i switch to different reports?

Comment: You can attach any functionality to button by adding a JavaScript code. E.g.:  Switching to different dashboard file / Hiding & showing CDE components of a dashboard / Adjusting settings or datasource of particular CDE component anf refreshing it.

Comment: can you please guide me the function that can be called to update the reporting component with difference reports?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe, create a new stackoverflow question for it.

Comment: Okay brother, i will, how can then i invite you to view it?

Comment: i have posted a new question, can you please have a look?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602251/pentaho-single-dashboard-for-multiple-reports-using-ajax