# Pentaho single Dashboard for multiple reports using ajax

Tags: ajax, report, pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-spoon

I have made multiple copies of dashboard for different reports to render. so url changes for each report in the browser and whole page needs to be refreshed.

Day before yesterday i came to know that any component can be refreshed [ [Refresh all components of Pentaho CDE dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356390/refresh-all-components-of-pentaho-cde-dashboard/) ]

I wanna know if i can use single pentaho dashboard to render different reports over single reporting component, using ajax calls by clicking different buttons/links?

I feel there should be some way arround this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you attach screenshots of the multiple dashboards? It would be easier to analyze your goal.

Comment: @mzy please check the image, i have updated the post
you can see the links on the left, there are reports links as well, for each report i have made new dashbaord which reloads the page, i want if i can call the reports via ajax using single dashboard for reports? browser url changes for each report.

Comment: Yes, now it is more understandable. Do you want the menu to be fixed, right? I know there is a way to make it fixed. You can go to marketplace and install plugin from `Ivy components`. There is a `Ivy` demo which source codes should help. Another approach which I have implemented is a dashboard where HTML divs (with CDE components) are `showing/hiding` depending on your JS context variable. Or you can attach onclick function which executes code: `document.getElementById(divToHide).style.display = 'block' / 'none'`

Comment: `Shop Daily Dashboard` and `Daily Dashboard > CDE Layout tab` screens would also help.

Comment: @mzy i have uploaded the new picture, my question is regarding the reports actually, see the links, each link is opened using seperate dashboard where i have used reporting component and assigned it rprt file. how to make single dashboard for REPORTS ONLY

Comment: I have no experience with including `rprt` files within dashboards.

Comment: ohhhh no problem @mzy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109161/discussion-between-shzyincu-and-mzy).

Comment: Hello @shzyincu I'm new to Pentaho and I aim to build something like you did. Is there any tutorial you would suggest? Or even the code if it is ok for you! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after so many attempts, i have figured it out that i can use single `prpt` component and update the action on button/anchor click, and then update the `prpt` component.

I tried this:

```
Dashboards.getComponent('render_prpt').action = "another_report";

Dashboards.getComponent('render_prpt').update();
```

and it worked :)