# How to update components in Pentaho CDE?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to refresh components in Pentaho CDE using a button. How can I do that?

Solution:
Finally, I created a button with an event click and a generic component like a parameter. The components that I wanted to refresh, I added them a listener with my custom parameter.
On the event click of the button, it calls the función:
 Dashboard.fireChanges ("myparam", "*");
All the components that I needed was refreshed!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh all components of Pentaho CDE dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356390/refresh-all-components-of-pentaho-cde-dashboard)

Comment: Don't put "SOLVED" in your title. Accept the answer that solved your problem

Comment: Don't put answers in your question. Put them in *answers*.

Comment: I didn't know that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use below function

> function updateAllDashboardComponents() {
>           Dashboards.updateAll(Dashboards.components);
>   }

Comment: I don't want to refresh all components

Answer (score 0):

If it's helpful to update a specific component with name *nameOfTheComponent* and not all of them you can do something like this:

```
var component = dashboard.getComponent('render_nameOfTheComponent');
dashboard.update(component);
```